# Table rows wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: reactjs

I have a table like this :

```
return (
            <tr key={key.dataKey}>
                <td>
                    <SuggestBox delay={1000} method={'post'} url={url} onPriceChange={this.handlePrice.bind(this)} index={i}/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Quantity refValue={key.quantity} />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>{key.price == 0 ? 'Waiting...' : ' $' + key.price.toFixed(2)}</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, i)}> X </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
```

But When I tried to put another TR in this render function, react gives me wrapping error. But I can't wrap them in a simple div. How to bypass this error ?

What I want is something like that :

```
return (
            <tr key={key.dataKey}>
                <td>
                    <SuggestBox delay={1000} method={'post'} url={url} onPriceChange={this.handlePrice.bind(this)} index={i}/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Quantity refValue={key.quantity} />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>{key.price == 0 ? 'Waiting...' : ' $' + key.price.toFixed(2)}</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, i)}> X </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

           //Putting this gives me an error..
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4">Some message</td>
            </tr>
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since React 16 you can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). This example uses the [short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax):

```
return (
    <>
        <tr key={key.dataKey}>
          <td>
            <SuggestBox delay={1000} method={ 'post'} url={url} onPriceChange={this.handlePrice.bind(this)} index={i}/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Quantity refValue={key.quantity} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <b>{key.price == 0 ? 'Waiting...' : ' $' + key.price.toFixed(2)}</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button className="btn" onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, i)}>X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>

        //Putting this gives me an error..
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Some message</td>
        </tr>
    </>
)
```

**Old Answer:**

Wrap them in a `<tbody>` because you can have [multiple `tbody` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) in a table. According to MDN:

> Note that unlike `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<caption>` elements,
>   multiple `<tbody>` elements are permitted (if consecutive), allowing the
>   data-rows in long tables to be divided into different sections, each
>   separately formatted as needed.

```
return (
    <tbody>
        <tr key={key.dataKey}>
          <td>
            <SuggestBox delay={1000} method={ 'post'} url={url} onPriceChange={this.handlePrice.bind(this)} index={i}/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Quantity refValue={key.quantity} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <b>{key.price == 0 ? 'Waiting...' : ' $' + key.price.toFixed(2)}</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button className="btn" onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, i)}>X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>

        //Putting this gives me an error..
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Some message</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
)
```